# Is there an "in state" predicate in Umple's state machines?

Tags: state-machine, umple

In Umple state machines' guards, I'm missing an "in state" predicate that returns true if the state machine is in a given state.
Does this function exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Call the get function on the state machine to get the state, and then compare the result to the enumeration whose name is the state machine followed by a dot followed by the state. See below for an example where a query is being done in method m1()

```
class X {
  sm {
    s1 {
      a-> s2;
    }
    s2 {}
  }
  
  public m1 () {
    if(getSm()==Sm.s1) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

It is a good point that this should be documented in the user manual